# script will animate but not toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I'm running a script that should toggle up and down

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#movedown').toggle(function() {
$(".menu2").animate({top: '-=1512px'}, 500);
}, function() {
$(".menu2").animate({top: '+=1512px'}, 500);
});
});
```

it won't toggle http://toddheymandirector.com/index_mobile99.html but if I replace toggle with click it will slide down http://toddheymandirector.com/index_mobile88.html
what am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `jQuery.toggle` wrong,

> *.toggle( [duration ] [, complete ] )*
>
> **Description:** Display or hide the matched elements.

See: [jQuery.toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

`toggle` is meant to be used to show/hide the matched elements, not switch between two functions as you are trying to use it.

---

From what I understand, you want to make an element "wobble" up and down?

This should work:

```
$(".menu2").animate({top: '-=1512px'}, 500).animate({top: '+=1512px'}, 500)
```

Comment: thank you. So would .animate be appropriate to get the element to alternate between sliding up and down?

Comment: @REELHERO use a line of animates together: `$(".menu2").animate({top: '-=1512px'}, 500).animate({top: '+=1512px'}, 500)` and shove them in a while loop.

Comment: thank you. so like: $(document).ready(function(){ $(".menu2").animate({top: '-=1512px'}, 500).animate({top: '+=1512px'}, 500)  }); });

Comment: apologies: `$(document).ready(function(){ $('#movedown').click(function() { $(".menu2").animate({top: '-=1512px'}, 500).animate({top: '+=1512px'}, 500)  }); });`

Comment: i tried the above script it slides down and onclick again it slides up a few pixels then slides back down: http://toddheymandirector.com/index_mobile888.html